# How to display a list of the foreignkey items?

Tags: django, model

I am struggling to display the list of foreignkey items. I can display the list of categories. But I don`t manage to display the list of times belonging to this category. For example, I would like to display the models belonging to the category, if we consider they belonging to the same category:

1. Meat Pizza
2. Veg Pizza

**models.py**

```
class PizzaCategory(models.Model):

    PIZZA_CATEGORY = (      
        (1, 'Meat'),
        (2, 'Fish'),
        (3, 'Vegetarian'),        
        )
    
        name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
        category = models.IntegerField(choices=PIZZA_CATEGORY,default=1)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.name
    
    class PizzaTopping(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=60, unique=True)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.name
    
    class MeatPizza(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=60, unique=True)
        pizza_category = models.ForeignKey(PizzaCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
        pizza_topping = models.ForeignKey(PizzaTopping, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.name
    
    class VegPizza(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=60, unique=True)
        pizza_category = models.ForeignKey(PizzaCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
        veg_type = models.CharField(max_length=60, unique=True)
        pizza_topping = models.ForeignKey(PizzaTopping, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.name
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required(login_url="/login/")
def category_detail(request, category_id):
    category = get_object_or_404(PizzaCategory, pk=category_id)
    categorys = PizzaCategory.objects.all()
    
    context = {
                'categorys': categorys,
               
              }
    return render(request, 'pizzas/category_detail.html', context)
```

**category_detail.html**

```
<tbody>
      {% for category in categorys.all %}
      <tr>                                               
         <td>{{ category.name }}</td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright,
Try in your HTML to write:

```
{% for category in categorys %}
```

deleting ".all"

I often also write it like so for the .py file:

```
return render(request, 'pizzas/category_detail.html', {
           'categorys': categorys,
            })
```

even though I know context is best practice.

ALSO :

MAke sure you have imported the model at the top of the .py file like so:

```
from .models import PizzaCategory
```

or this for all of them:

```
from .models import *
```

Comment: This is for displaying all category. I am looking for displaying any models related to this category.

Comment: did you import the models in the .py file?

Comment: I did. This works fine if I want to display the category. I would like to display the models. The list should look like: 1. {{ MeatPizza.name }} 2. {{ VegPizza.name }}